# How can I restrict the type of a parameter in Android Jetpack Compose with Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I can use Code A to display a dialog of edit box. In fact,   the parameter  `editTextConten`   need to accept a variable  just like  `var editContent by remember { mutableStateOf("Hello") }` .

How can I restrict a type of parameter ?

BTW, the Code B and Code C are wrong.

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun DisplayEditBox(
    editTextContent:String,
    onChangEditTextContent: (String) ->Unit
) {
    TextField(
        value = editTextContent,
        onValueChange = onChangEditTextContent
    )
}

@Composable
fun ScreenHome_Line() {
    var editContent by remember { mutableStateOf("Hello") }
    DisplayEditBox(editContent) {
        editContent = it
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
@Composable
fun DisplayEditBox(
    editTextContent:String = remember {mutableStateOf("") },
    onChangEditTextContent: (String) ->Unit
) {
    TextField(
        value = editTextContent,
        onValueChange = onChangEditTextContent
    )
}
```

**Code C**

```
@Composable
fun DisplayEditBox(
    editTextContent:String by remember {mutableStateOf("") },
    onChangEditTextContent: (String) ->Unit
) {
    TextField(
        value = editTextContent,
        onValueChange = onChangEditTextContent
    )
}
```

Comment: It is incorrect encapsulation to try to do this. Code A is correct. It is up to the caller of the function to decide if the String should be State or remembered. If you don't want to hoist your state, then don't hoist it--declare it inside this function. Anyway, there is no way to enforce it without writing a very complicated Lint rule. I'm not sure if it's even possible. `@DrawableRes` is already quite complicated and it doesn't even work reliably.

Answer (score 1):

You can use State<*> as type.

```
@Composable
fun DisplayEditBox(
    editTextContent: State<String>,
    onChangEditTextContent: (String) -> Unit
) {
    TextField(
        value = editTextContent.value,
        onValueChange = onChangEditTextContent
    )
}

@Composable
fun ScreenHome_Line() {
    val editContent = remember { mutableStateOf("Hello") }
    DisplayEditBox(editContent) {
        editContent.value = it
    }
}
```

Now you can send only State value as parameter and it will force call site to handle state for your code. And prevent call site to send raw string as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do that, but you can do the [state hoisting](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state-hoisting), which is what you're advised to do as in the first example.

Comment: Thanks! I hope the Android  compiler can give a warning information when a normal String variable is passed to  `editTextContent:String` .

Comment: Just like `@DrawableRes avatarRes: Int,` ,it means that the parameter only accept a int of   `@DrawableRes`.